# How to prevent a image from scrolling in a scrollview?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a scrollview with lots of buttons in it,I have a header-imageview with close-button and a title-label in it.the problem is when I scroll the scrollview the header-image also scrolls up.I don't want this,how can I stop scrolling the header-image with the other buttons.
How can I do this?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a UIScrollView or a UItableview?

Comment: I guess we need some code or visualization, sometimes these things can be hard to visualize by just a description.

Comment: i place the scrollview inside the uiview and set it content size propert correctly in viewdidload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

- You can subclass `UIScrollView` and override `layoutSubviews` to reposition your header view.
- You can assign a delegate to your `UIScrollView` and implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` in the delegate to reposition your header view.

The [WWDC 2011 session video "Advanced ScrollView Techniques"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) explains how to do it.  In the video it is called a "stationary view".  Go watch it.

Answer (score 0):

Preparing a parent view to which both scroll view and header image will be attached as subviews  should do.

Comment: yea you are correct,i already done this way,but my content inside the scrollview didint scroll in parent view.

Comment: Did you set the contentSize property of UIScrollView correctly?